# XmlReader 'Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType when read with ReadElementContentAsString

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

I'm trying to read the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<recipe>
  <name>5 SE</name>
  <timecreated>02.11.2015 13:13:36</timecreated>
  <min>90</min>
  <max>130</max>
  <range>40</range>
  <avg>110</avg>
  <stddev>40</stddev>
</recipe>
```

My code looks like this:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("data.xml");
reader.ReadStartElement("recipe");
reader.ReadStartElement("name");
String content = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("name", "");´
```

On the last line it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 3,
>   position 9.

Why is 'Text' an invalid node type? ReadElementContentAsString sounds like it could easily return the 'Text' as a string.

Comment: You already consumed the tag name so all you need to do is get value : string content = reader.Value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReadElementContentAsString` reads the element AND its content together. So either you should not consume the `<name>` node, or use just `ReadContentAsString` instead.

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("data.xml", new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true });
reader.ReadStartElement("recipe");
// reader.ReadStartElement("name"); - now you will be at the <name> element instead of "5 SE" text
String content = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("name", "");
```

Comment: Ok. I also tried that before. It gives me another XmlException as the call to ReadElementContentAsString(): 'Whitespace' is an invalid XmlNodeType

Comment: You should ignore the non-significant whitespaces, then. See my modified answer.